# How to make a object visible only once at first launch in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am trying to display a Terms & Conditions for the user when the app is launched. Once the user press "Ok". i don't want to display it again from next launch. Can anyone guide me how to achieve this. currently i am getting the T&C on every launch. I want it only for first launch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possiblility is to use `PlayerPrefs` class. Set a key when you display T&C and when the next time you are going to display T&C first check the PlayerPrefs value and if it is set don't display T&C.

e.g.,

Set key:

```
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("hasTCDisplayed", true);
```

Check before displaying T&C:

```
if(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("hasTCDisplayed") == false)
{
  // Display Terms & Condition
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, will check and get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `playerprefs.setInt` and set a flag after the first show then check the value of it before showing your dialog

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!PlayerPrefs.HasKey("FirstTime")) 
{
    //Show T&C Here
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("FirstTime",1);
}
```